# How to fix mistake specifying partition sizes during installation alongside other OS?

Tags: 11.10, installation, dual-boot

I wanted to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.

When it asked me to allocate the partition size I by mistake dragged the panel. I was unaware of that it will allocate that size for Ubuntu. And I had 27 gb free space in memory and Now i have 6 GB left. And also the Ubuntu installation is also not complete. I want to reclaim that space and Install ubuntu along woth the Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for the installation to finish, or cancel it. Boot from the bootable USB/CD that you have made and click  "Try Ubuntu." Open the partition manager, unmount all partitions, and resize from there.

Just FYI, the reason you can't resize the partitions from Linux (after installation) is that the partition is in use and cannot be unmounted.

- Similarly, this is why resizing from Disk Management in Windows Vista/7--which only works for Windows partitions, not Ubuntu partitions--causes the operation to be scheduled for shutdown rather than being able to perform it immediately.